# Difference between last_modified_time and last_ddl_time in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

In Hive when we use the following command : **SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ;**
It returns a list of metadata related to the particular table . Out of those metadata, there are two fields i am confused between.

**'last_modified_time'='1620814731',
'transient_lastDdlTime'='1620820769'**

What is the underlying difference between these two metrics ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get lastaltertimestamp from Hive table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045273/how-to-get-lastaltertimestamp-from-hive-table)